# How to redirect from non eng to /eng/ in url path I am getting redirect loop (Right now in localhost but need both live and local)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, git-rewrite-history

Thank you for your time. I have done almost everything but I am stuck here in the redirect part
Here is my full .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ecom-book/eng/
RewriteRule ^ecom-book/(.*)$ /ecom-book/eng/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^eng/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*) product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

ErrorDocument 403 /cgi-sys/403_def.html
ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-sys/404_def.html
ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-sys/500_def.html
ErrorDocument 502 /cgi-sys/502_def.html
ErrorDocument 503 /cgi-sys/503_def.html
ErrorDocument 504 /cgi-sys/504_def.html

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.in$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.in\/" [R=301,L]

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

This code dont work as expected to I have handled to ignore /eng/ too.

But I am having issue when I added this line-

```
# Redirect to the /eng/ version of genre.php if /eng/ is not present in the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ecom-book/eng/
RewriteRule ^ecom-book/(.*)$ /ecom-book/eng/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It goes into redirect loop if I dont include ecom-book
I have this url I hit - https://localhost/ecom-book/genre.php
And want a redirection to - https://localhost/ecom-book/eng/genre.php
WHEN /eng/ is not present after localhost/ecom-book/

Please help me fix that issue I tried some already answered if you have any answer to refer to thanks a lot for you time.
Please let me know a fix for both localhost and live server with domain

Comment: "It goes into redirect loop **if I dont include ecom-book**" - To clarify, the example URLs and directives all _include_ `ecom-book`, so you only get a redirect loop if you **don't include** `ecom-book`?? What is the nature of the redirect loop exactly? (The rule in your _complete_ `.htaccess` file has an additional _condition_?) You should be testing with a 302 (temp) redirect. Please make sure your browser cache is cleared.

Comment: But @MrWhite even 302 is not working I did it instead of 301. Actually the above code is just working fine /eng/ also works but I need it to be strict to redirect if /eng/ is not present. That is the exact short Problem. Thank you

Comment: So, what is the "redirect loop" you speak of in the question? Is there a redirect loop? Why do you inject `/eng/` if missing from requests that start `/ecom-book/`, but remove `/eng/` from the start of the URL-path? And how are these URLs routed? Are they static file requests? It's unclear what your question is?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite I have done this approach in php itself but with your help that will be best with .htaccess, I have 3 languages like hin, eng, ben - Now I want to add those languages so that I can process them in php and i want if nothing is there like /ben/ or /hin/ or /eng/ by default add the /eng/ to the url like localhost/ecom-book/eng/genre.php like that So i just need your help with redirection to /eng/ if the url has nothing like user has not put any language or url is - localhost/ecom-book/genre.php to /eng/genre.php

Comment: You should first of all move that block that rewrite to HTTPS and removes the `www.` prefix, to the top. Doing that later on, after other rewrites might already have happened, is usually asking for trouble.